# Is there a way to vectorize this pandas apply method to make the code run faster?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Currently it is taking 40 - 50 mins to run ~220K rows

```
shop    timestamp   flag
10061   1577525275  NaN
10061   1577534732  NaN
10061   1577741715  NaN
10061   1577741800  NaN
10084   1577405286  NaN
```

```
def foo(row):
    criteria = (pd.isnull(df2.flag)) & (df.shop==row.shop) & (abs(df.timestamp-row.timestamp) <= 3600)
    df2.loc[criteria, 'flag'] = 1
```

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

What I'm doing is for each row in the df2, I'm check against the main df to see if in the same shop, what other rows have timestamp within the hour and set the flag as 1. Is there a way to use numpy vectors to make this run much faster?

Expected output:

```
shop    timestamp   flag
10061   1577525275  NaN
10061   1577534732  NaN
10061   1577741715  1
10061   1577741800  1
10084   1577405286  NaN
```

Comment: it helps when you post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do your task a quicker way, define the following function:

```
def newFlag(grp):
    tt = grp.timestamp
    ind = np.nonzero(np.triu(np.absolute(tt[np.newaxis, :] - tt[:, np.newaxis]) <= 3600, 1))
    tbl = grp.flag.values
    tbl[np.concatenate(ind)] = 1
    return pd.Series(np.where(np.isnan(grp.flag), tbl, grp.flag), index=grp.index)
```

Then apply it, saving the result in *flag* column:

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby('shop').apply(newFlag).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

The speed of this solution is based on grouping by *shop*, so you don't have to
compare rows concerning different shops.

Another important factor concerning the speed is employment of *Numpy* functions,
which operate much quicker than *Pandas*.

To fully comprehend all details, run this code step-by-step for a chosen group
of rows (for particular *shop*) and look at the results.

Comment: this is brilliant. I never thought of it - this runs for 10s only. I suppose it's using matrix subtraction? since it's row vector subtract with col vector, it's taking difference from everything and the groupby ensures all shop rows! I don't get why np.triu? is it because it's symmetric?

Comment: Usage of *triu* is needed to iterate over the upper triangular part of
the difference result (you're right, it is symmetric).
Note also that *k* argument is set to *1*, to omit the diagonal, where
each element is *0* (the distance from element No *x* to itself).

Comment: is there a way to flag the records with incremental number? for e.g. now it's flag as all 1's but I can't tell which orders are grouped as one hour interval together.

Comment: Your post doesn't contain any requirements on this matter. Maybe you should sort rows by *shop* and then by *timestamp*?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your dataframe by shop, then sort each group by timestamp, and finally only check the previous and next rows:

```
print(df)
    shop   timestamp
0  10061  1577525275
1  10061  1577534732
2  10061  1577741715
3  10061  1577741800
4  10084  1577405286


def have_similar(df):
    df = df.sort_values('timestamp')
    df = df.assign(
        flag = (df.timestamp - df.timestamp.shift(1) < 3600) |
               (df.timestamp.shift(-1) - df.timestamp < 3600)
    )
    return df

result = df.groupby('shop').apply(have_similar).reset_index(drop=True)


print(result)
    shop   timestamp   flag
0  10061  1577525275  False
1  10061  1577534732  False
2  10061  1577741715   True
3  10061  1577741800   True
4  10084  1577405286  False
```